# Command line arguments in wxWidgets

Tags: c++, command-line, wxwidgets

Is there a way I can read the command line arguments passed into a C++ wxWidgets application? If so, could you please provide an example of how to do so.

Comment: Your `main` function has two arguments, normally called `argc` and `argv`. Those are the command line arguments passed to your application, and which you pass on to wxWidgets. Just check those arguments to `main` yourself if you need to.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: I am not sure if you are familiar with how wxWidgets programs initialized, however, they typically use wxFrame and wxApplication windows and you don't plainly have access to those two variables.

Comment: If there's no methods in the application class to get the parameters, maybe you have to re-implement the `IMPLEMENT_APP` macro, to get the arguments from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at these examples ([1](http://wiki.wxwidgets.org/Command-Line_Arguments), [2](https://web.archive.org/web/20090517040330/http://id.motd.org/pivot/entry.php?id=15)) or:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) 
{ 
    wxApp::CheckBuildOptions(WX_BUILD_OPTIONS_SIGNATURE, "program"); 

    wxInitializer initializer; 
    if (!initializer) 
    { 
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to initialize the wxWidgets library, aborting."); 
        return -1; 
    } 

    static const wxCmdLineEntryDesc cmdLineDesc[] = 
    { 
        { wxCMD_LINE_SWITCH, "h", "help", "show this help message", 
            wxCMD_LINE_VAL_NONE, wxCMD_LINE_OPTION_HELP }, 
        // ... your other command line options here... 

        { wxCMD_LINE_NONE } 
    }; 

    wxCmdLineParser parser(cmdLineDesc, argc, wxArgv); 
    switch ( parser.Parse() ) 
    { 
        case -1: 
            wxLogMessage(_T("Help was given, terminating.")); 
            break; 

        case 0: 
            // everything is ok; proceed 
            break; 

        default: 
            wxLogMessage(_T("Syntax error detected, aborting.")); 
            break; 
    } 
    return 0; 
}
```

Answer (score 8):

In plain C++, there is `argc` and `argv`. When you are building a wxWidgets application, you can access these using `wxApp::argc`, `wxApp::argv[]` or `wxAppConsole::argc`, `wxAppConsole::argv[]`. Note that `wxApp` is derived from `wxAppConsole`, so either works depending on if you have a console app or GUI app. See [wxAppConsole](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_app_console.html)

```
IMPLEMENT_APP(MyApp)

bool MyApp::OnInit() {
// Access command line arguments with wxApp::argc, wxApp::argv[0], etc.
// ...
}
```

You may also be interested in [wxCmdLineParser](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_cmd_line_parser.html).

Comment: Thank you JohnPS, its exactly what i need.

Answer (score 1):

You can access the command line variables from your `wxApp` as it inherites from `wxAppConsole` which provides [wxAppConsole::argc](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_app_console.html#a18d2288273cee260ff047831a5e8bfc5)
 and  [wxAppConsole::argv](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_app_console.html#aec036ffd2b28e72ca36cb0f7ef6a3b37).