# which library to use to parse command line arguments in C++

Tags: c++, c, linux, boost, getopt

I know about `getopts` and [`argp`](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Argp.html). I just looked in `boost` and they have `program_options` as a library for parsing command-line parameters.

I'm not exactly sure which one to use. I know `getopts` is `POSIX`, while `argp` isn't but that doesn't matter to me. What matters is ease of use. Can you recommend (pros/cons?) one. I'm open to other libraries too.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you want something lightweight and easy to use, then you might be interested in [`TCLAP`](http://tclap.sourceforge.net/) (header only, liberal license). ([example](http://tclap.sourceforge.net/manual.html#EXAMPLE))

Otherwise [`boost::program_options`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/doc/html/program_options.html) (also liberal license) provides virtually anything one could need. ([example](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/doc/html/program_options/tutorial.html#id2499896))

Finally if you are already using a framework/library ([WxWidgets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10118342/command-line-arguments-in-wxwidgets/10118492#10118492), Qt) that has some command-line argument handling then probably the simplest option is to stick with that framework.

Answer (score 2):

You could also use [popt](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl3_popt.htm).

If you are using a graphical toolkit like Gtk (thru GtkMM if in C++) or Qt, each of these offer their own command line arguments parsing facilities.

Answer (score 1):

glibmm has Glib::OptionContext. It's quite simple but does what most people need, in a standard way. It's not well documented, but here is an example that shows most of what it can do: http://git.gnome.org/browse/glibmm/tree/examples/options/main.cc

It wraps the GOptionContext C API in glib.